# How do you PEP 8-name a class whose name is an acronym?

Tags: python, coding-style, naming-conventions

I try to adhere to the style guide for Python code (also known as [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)). Accordingly, the preferred way to name a class is using CamelCase:

> Almost without exception, class names
>   use the CapWords convention. Classes for internal use have a leading underscore in addition.

How can I be consistent with PEP 8 if my class name is formed by two acronyms (which in proper English should be capitalized). For instance, if my class name was 'NASA JPL', what would you name it?:

```
class NASAJPL():  # 1
class NASA_JPL(): # 2
class NasaJpl():  # 3
```

I am using #1, but it looks weird; #3 looks weird too, and #2 seems to violate PEP 8.

Comment: @fuzzy: I fail to understand how JPL (Jet Propulsion Laboratory) is not an acronym, while NASA (National Aeronautics and Space Administration) is. I also fail to understand how someone thought your comment is great, but that can be attributed to my own inadequacies. :)

Comment: An acronym is an abbreviation spoken as a word.
Do you say JPL as a word, Like JayPul? No you say the letters, J,P,L. That is an abbreviation.

Comment: Consider the broader toolset of Python - specially pylint-type tools. They are poor at spotting English-language within Python class, method and variable names. Think of Python as a foreign language and not a English-language dialect may allow you to "let go" of uppercase acronyms and use #3 #opinion

Comment: As an outsider, I can tell that `NasaJpl` are two different acronyms. That should be a hint for you. Readability is more important than some human-made random rule

Comment: JPL is not an acronym nor an abbreviation.  It's an initialism.  An abbreviation is something that is shortened.  So for "Jet Propulsion Laboratory" down to "Jet Propulsion Lab" for example.

Comment: While `NASA` is considerably a well accepted acronym, `JPL` is not. If this is designed for usage outside of a certain group, it should be spelled out. Otherwise, it should be fine to go with a less _standard_ name. So I would vote for `NASAJetPropulsionLaboratory`.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

[PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) does cover this (at least partially):

> Note: When using acronyms in CapWords, capitalize all the letters of the acronym. Thus `HTTPServerError` is better than `HttpServerError`.

Which I would read to mean that `NASAJPL()` is the recommended name according to PEP-8.

Personally I'd find `NasaJpl()` the [easiest to scan](http://www.garrettreil.ie/design-research-blog_files/Use-of-English-in-Irish-sign-design.php) since the upper case letters easily mark word boundaries and give the name a distinctive shape.

Comment: I agree. PEP-8 isn't Holy Law. Break any of its rules sooner than code anything outright barbarous. (In which category I would count `NASAJPL()`.)

Comment: @bobince: That's what PEP-8 is stating itself. IMHO one of the most important parts!
"A style guide is about consistency. Consistency with this style guide is important. Consistency within a project is more important. Consistency within one module or function is most important. " (PEP-8)

Comment: Are you using pylint or similar? Did such a tool have an impact on your naming convention decision?

Comment: To sort of reinforce that this answer is correct, in https://github.com/python/peps/issues/624 someone suggested amending PEP-8 to clarify how pronounceable acronyms should be capitalized. A Python Core developer said, "I would definitely recommend `NASARocketsList` over `NasaRocketList` but of course, individual developers are free to choose what makes the most sense. ... I certainly wouldn't ding anyone for writing it as `ScubaGearChecklist`" and "personally I don't think PEP 8 needs to elaborate on the differences."

Answer (score 42):

As others have noted, `NASAJPL` is probably the PEP-8 approved form.

Just to be contrary, however, I would probably use `NasaJPL`.  Because if you are reading it, you pronounce "NASA" as a single word, whereas "JPL" you spell out.

You can make an argument that this is consistent with PEP-8, since "NASA" is an acronym, but "JPL" is an abbreviation (or initialism, if you want to get [pedantic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acronym_and_initialism)).

Answer (score 13):

`#1` in this particular case looks fine to me (if it's *really* an acronym). Out of curiosity, what does it stand for (and what exactly is the class instance, maybe a `module` would be the more appropriate divisor)?

```
class NASAJPL:
```

When you're combining two acronyms chances are you want to divide functionality over modules (you never know when you're adding that next feature to your program):

```
from NASA import JPL
from NASA import ARC
```

Comment: The problem with #1 is that `NASAJPL`, `JPL` and `ARC` look like symbolic constants, for which all-caps is used both in PEP8 and in the wider world.

Answer (score 12):

I also work in an acronym-heavy environment. I tend to prefer form #3 because even though it lower-cases parts of an acronym, it clearly delineates parts of the name. It also avoids confusion when part of the name is an acronym and part is a word.

Answer (score 11):

### You're Doing it Right.

If [ChristophD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/81179/christophed)'s [split it into a module hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853531/how-do-you-pep-8-name-a-class-whose-name-is-an-acronym/2853562#2853562) suggestion isn't a viable option, then I'd suggest your #2 form (`class NASA_JPL ():`) is the most legible, PEP-8 be damned.

### No, really...

That said... I don't think PEP-8 need be damned in order for you to use that option *and* still adhere to its core principles. As you point out in your original question, itself, the first sentence of the "CamelCase class names" guideline begins:

> Almost without exception, [...]

PEP-8's "fundamental principles" statement, as [Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55155/dan) alludes to with the ["A Foolish Consistency [...]"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853531/how-do-you-pep-8-name-a-class-whose-name-is-an-acronym/2853590#2853590) line, declares legibility and comprehensibility the primary goals of PEP-8's recommendations. PEP-8 is a collection of established, successful patterns in service to those goals.

### *[Emerson](http://www.bartleby.com/100/420.47.html)* on the application of PEP-8 to reality...

Fundamentally, any system has aspects which are necessarily inconsistent with the character of the whole. When a system makes good and consistent use of a style guide's recommendations, any inconsistencies will be *conscious* responses to *necessity*. (I regard maintaining the legibility of corner cases as a necessity.)

When handled this way, those inconsistencies, counter-intuitively, reinforce the cohesion of the whole, rather than disrupting it.

PEP-8 states this more succinctly (and, thus, more usefully):

> But most importantly: know when to be inconsistent -- sometimes the style
> guide just doesn't apply.  When in doubt, use your best judgment.  Look
> at other examples and decide what looks best.  And don't hesitate to ask!
>
> Two good reasons to break a particular rule:
>
> 1. When applying the rule would make the code less readable, even for someone who is used to reading code that follows the rules.
> 2. To be consistent with surrounding code that also breaks it (maybe for historic reasons)—although this is also an opportunity to clean up someone else's mess (in true XP style).

Comment: Agreed. NASA_JPL is just as readable as NasaJpl, but the former is more accurate and informative. The only reason to prefer NasaJpl is python style consistency, but even the style guide emphasizes that clarity and correctness supersedes style. Both NASA and JPL are well known acronyms for established institutions. For example, if you were creating a configuration class for the United States Department of Justice, USA_DOJ_config() is more accurate and informative than UsaDojConfig().

Comment: @KMaize I'm not with you on it being "informative" since it doesn't inform me whether I'm looking at constant vs class name. The style guide is designed to convey this information. `NASA_JPL` more naturally looks like a constant until you carefully read it to discover it's a name that happens to be comprised of acronyms.  Even once you know this, you can't distinguish between the two.  That moment between *seeing* and *reading* is what makes this less readable and more prone to misreads.

Comment: @PhilipCouling You are right that `NASA_JPL` decreases readability with respect to what it represents in a python program. Is it a constant or class name? However, `NASA_JPL` improves readability with respect to the actual thing it represents in the real world. (You would never see NasaJpl used outside of a computer program.) This dilemma occurs frequently with acronyms and the preferred approach depends on context. Style guides are suggestions, not rules. Any program that assumes an object's type based on its spelling or capitalization is asking for trouble.

Comment: @KMaize you wouldn't see `PowerTransformer` or `power_transformer` outside code either so that argument falls flat. Context is very important. I notice that PEP8 doesn't make any direct suggestion of what to do in the case of class names which are entirely acronyms, I suspect that was a deliberate omission precisely because context changes everything.  As for what's most readable I'd be tempted to go with`NASAJPL` as the inclusion of the underscore is a trip hazard. Suffice to say I don't find `NASA_JPL` more readable than `NasaJPL` at all.

Answer (score 8):

I tend to use #3.  It looks weird at first but you (sort of) get used to it.  I went this way after suffering for too long under strings of acronyms jammed together, e.g. NPCAIXMLParser was one.  I decided that NpcAiXmlParser was much easier to read and have been doing that ever since, even though seeing these things lowercased still looks weird sometimes.

In terms of "the standards," I tend to think of these entities as "words" and as such capitalize them as I would capitalize any other word.  E.g. if I had a local variable representing some NPC (non-player character), I would name it 'npc' and not 'nPC'.

In regards to PEP-8, I disagree with this statement; I find the last spelling of the word to be preferable.

> Note: When using abbreviations in
>   CapWords, capitalize all the letters
>   of the abbreviation.  Thus
>   HTTPServerError is better than
>   HttpServerError.

Answer (score 3):

Number 1 is too hard to read for me - there's no way to tell that's it's two acronyms.

Number 2 violates PEP8, but looks fine. Remember "A foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of little minds"

I like number 3 the best, but I do a lot of C# programming - that's how you'd be supposed to do it in C#.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the acronym. Another option would be `class NASAJpl():`, which makes it seem that "NASA" is the primary part, and "JPL" is the subordinate part.