# Python naming convention for abbreviation

Tags: python, naming-conventions

I want to get a variable naming in a consistent way

I think cgi is an abbreviation,so it should be CGI

Should I change the set_camera_cgi to `set_camera_CGI`

But what if cgi_set_prefix to `CGI_set_prefix`,

Therefore the variable will start with a upcase, will it be more worse?

```
def set_camera_cgi(self, set_CGI_lst):
    try:
        cgi_set_prefix=''.join([
            "http://",
            self.conn_cfg["ip"],
            self.cgi["set"]])

        cgi_get_prefix=''.join([
            "http://",
            self.conn_cfg["ip"],
            self.cgi["get"]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Name abbreviations using the usual lowercase convention (e.g. the `cgi` module, not the `CGI` module). Basically, name everything according to PEP 8 when reasonable (even abbreviations).

Comment: But he suggested capitalize all the letters of the abbreviation , so I'm kind of confused http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853531/how-do-you-pep-8-name-a-class-whose-name-is-an-acronym

Comment: Only `When using abbreviations in CapWords`. So, you would always write `nasa_jpl` in a function or variable name.

Comment: so even in module name(filename), I should use cgi_automation.py , not the CGI_automation.py , it's a more common convention , right ? Only use `Class CGIAutomation ` in camel case, that is class name, right ?

Comment: Yep. You should use the lowercase for naming the files. And yep to the class name, too.